# How to delay this message in screen

Tags: android, delay, progressdialog

I need to get this message on the screen for 3 seconds and it is important that the process is running in the background. Thanks

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage(getText(R.string.wait));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Is that part of an async task nested in an activity? What's not working? Do you actually have a question?

Comment: I need is that the message is displayed on the screen for 3000 milliseconds. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you want to show it for the duration of what ever is happening in async task, close it in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner, how would the code?